# How to change directory inside bash script from Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkinsfile I have cloned one git repo using Git SCM and for relativeTargetDir I added for example "myGit". 
So it is saved in directory "myGit".

After that I need to run my bash script, and inside after executing some lines of codes, I need to go inside myGit folder to be able to run some tests.
But I'm always getting cd: myGit: No such file or directory.

In my bash script I have tried like this :

```
some code...
cd myGit
run some tests inside myGit directory...
```

But when I try in Jenkinsfile like this :

```
dir('myGit') {
   run some tests inside myGit directory...
}
```

it's working.

But I need to do that in my bash script.

Expected result : to go inside myGit directory

Actual result : throws cd: myGit: No such file or directory.

Comment: Could you please add your complete jenkins file. Also, login jenkins agent where the job is executed and check that this folder really exists. Also, you can try `dir("myGit") {sh "pwd"}`

Answer (score 0):

you can always do a

`sh 'cd myGit && run some tests inside myGit directory`